# Optionally supporting initializer_list construction for templates maybe wrapping containers

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, initializer-list, enable-if

If I have a template that wraps a standard container, it seems I can reasonably easily delegate the initializer_list constructor:

```
template<typename T>
struct holder {
    T t_;

    holder() :
        t_() {}

    holder(std::initializer_list<typename T::value_type> values)
        : t_(values) {}

};
```

So this works nicely with std::vector, for instance.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    holder<std::vector<int>> y{1,2,3};
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But it pretty obviously doesn't work for T as 'int', or any other type that doesn't have a nested value_type typedef. So, I'd like to use some sort of enable_if or similar trick to make the initializer_list constructor not be emitted unless T both defines a nested value_type typedef, and is constructible from std::initializer_list.

I tried the following, but it still doesn't work, because the compiler (clang++ 3.1 in my case), still trips over the invalid T::value_type when T is int:

```
holder(typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<T, std::initializer_list<typename T::value_type>>::value, std::initializer_list<typename T::value_type>>::type values)
    : t_(values) {}
```

Any thoughts on how to express the concept "give this template on T an initializer list constructor over T's value_type, if and only if T has a value_type typedef and is constructible from an initializer_list of T::value_type".

Comment: Is the `initializer_list` passed by value correct, or should it be passed by some reference type? (`&&` ?)

Comment: @MartinBa: pass by value is correct (and recommended) for `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: An `initializer_list` just contains a pointer and a size, so it is ok to pass it by value. The data itself is not copied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SFINAE only works on template parameter subsitution(hence the S in SFINAE). The following works:

```
template<typename T>
struct holder {
    T t_;

    holder() :
        t_() {}

    template<typename U = T>
    holder(typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<U, std::initializer_list<typename U::value_type>>::value, 
    std::initializer_list<typename U::value_type>>::type values)
    : t_(values) {}

};
```

If you didn't use a template function, then the whole class would be instantiated for the type `int`(in your example), leading to a compiler error.

Note that you could make the function signature nicer if you used an extra template parameter:

```
template<typename U = T, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<U, std::initializer_list<typename U::value_type>>::value, bool>::type>
    holder(std::initializer_list<typename U::value_type> values)
    : t_(values) {}
```

Comment: Interesting, but it doesn't quite work. With my original version `holder<std::vector<int>> y = {1, 2, 3}` works correctly, but at least with my compiler it does not work with your revised constructor signature. It complains that 'candidate constructor template not viable: requires 1 argument, but 3 were provided'

Comment: Couldn't you drop the enable_if and just use `template <typename U=T> holder(std::initializer_list<typename U::value_type> values)`?